# Visual Studio 2015 removing Typescript SourceMapping

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, source-maps

I'm using TypeScript in my Visual Studio Project. 
There are the following files:

- Example.ts
- Example.js.map
- Example.js

To Debug the TypeScript code in Chrome it is necessary to have this as the last line in the .js file

> //# sourceMappingURL=Example.js.map

But sometimes Visual Studio removes this line, and sometimes it adds it.
Everytime changing and saving the .ts file it removes the sourceMapping line.
When I build the whole project over Build -> Build "Project Name" it adds the sourcemapping line.

On the project configuration under *TypeScript Build* -> *Generate source maps* is enabled. *Compile on save* is also enabled.

It would be nice that Visual Studio does not remove the sourcemapping after changing and saving the .ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to fix this behaviour.
Need to add this to csproj file:

```
 <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
```

[Example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html)